# React Native fetch data error from REST api on https requests

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm using React Native to get some data from REST api which based on dotnet core.
There is a network error when I'm trying to get data from api on Android emulator however it works on IOS.

I've tried to get data using http instead of https and it works as well.

Comment: what errors are you getting? please include output of expected and unexpected output if possible

Comment: I am using axios and getting: [Error: Network Error] But i tried same code on iOS emulator and it's working.

Comment: could you add the entire error as printed by your IDE\terminal?

Answer (score 0):

Hi there to prevent network error on `http` you can add this line in the `AndroidManifest` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest ...>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <application
            ...
            android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" //<--- add this line
            ...>
            ...
        </application>
    </manifest>
```

Comment: I tried this.But http is working. I get error with https.

Comment: have you stringyfy your data in the request

Comment: If you can access with http but not with https, it could be a trust issue. With Secure Sockets Layer, you will need a trust certificate that allows you access to the site. You can check out this website for more details: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl